# Off-by-one errors in h2o data frame indexing for large indexes

Tags: r, h2o

We have been experiencing some odd (broken) behaviour at work when using large indexing sets with h2o data frames

The following code makes no changes to iris_h2o:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
data(iris)

iris<-rbind(iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris)
iris<-rbind(iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris)
iris<-rbind(iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris)

iris_h2o<-as.h2o(iris)

iris_h2o[c(1:1000),"Sepal.Length"]<-iris_h2o[c(1:1000),"Sepal.Length"]
iris_h2o
```

Output:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

However, if you increase the size of the indexing set to 1001, then suddenly it seems that the indexing between left and right sides becomes inconsistent

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
data(iris)

iris<-rbind(iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris)
iris<-rbind(iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris)
iris<-rbind(iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris,iris)

iris_h2o<-as.h2o(iris)


iris_h2o[c(1:1001),"Sepal.Length"]<-iris_h2o[c(1:1001),"Sepal.Length"]
iris_h2o
```

Output:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          5.1         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.9         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.7         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          4.6         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.0         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

This is confirmed on R 3.3.2 with h2o 3.10.0.8 as well as R 3.4.0 with the latest version of h2o available on CRAN (3.10.4.6)

We'd like to know what's causing this and how to avoid issues with this in the future

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "right and left side", can you explain?  Also, what is the point of this line: `iris_h2o[c(1:1001),"Sepal.Length"]<-iris_h2o[c(1:1001),"Sepal.Length"]`?  This replaces the first 1001 rows of "Sepal.Length" column with the same exact data (not sure why you'd do that).

Comment: Right and left sides - the expressions to the left and right of ->. The problem is that it is not replacing it with exact same data. Obviously, this is a minimal example to demonstrate the behaviour, it's not what we're actually doing

Comment: Got it, thanks for clarifying (I didn't notice that the two datasets were slightly different at first).  I will look into this.

Comment: I'm not as quick as Erin, and still confused - the output block is the same in the 1000 and the 1001 example? Can you expand a bit on what is the expected behaviour, and what is the (undesirable) behaviour you are getting?

Comment: Look at the second row. Sepal.Length is 4.9 in the first output, but 5.1 in the second output

Comment: We have confirmed the bug on our end and opened a ticket here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4438  @Richard Thank you very much for bringing this to our attention and providing a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks. You may want to merge it with the bug report my colleague submitted: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/projects/PUBDEV/issues/PUBDEV-4434?filter=addedrecently

Comment: I can confirm this is fixed in h2o 3.10.5.2 onwards